# Converting a string to a list of integers in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am trying to convert a string to a list of integers.

```
  String = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08".
```

But

```
  lists:map(fun(X) -> string:to_integer(X) end, string:tokens(String, " ")).
```

just gives me...

```
  [{8,[]}, {2,[]}, {22,[]}, {97,[]}, ... , {91,[]}, {8,[]}]
```

Can someone perhaps tell me what a good/nice way would be to get?

```
  [8,2,22,97...91,8]
```

(Or do I need a helper function?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
String = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08".
lists:map(fun(X) -> {Int, _} = string:to_integer(X), 
                    Int end, 
          string:tokens(String, " ")).

> [8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8]
```

See, `string:to_integer` returns not a single integer, but a tuple:

```
to_integer(String) -> {Int,Rest} | {error,Reason}
```

... so you have to extract the first element from this tuple to get the actual number.

Comment: I read the manual, but didn't realize this is possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you might use list generator syntax:

`[begin {Int,_}=string:to_integer(Token), Int end|| Token<-string:tokens(String," ")].`

From shell:

```
1> String = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08".
"08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08"
2> 
2> [begin {Int,_}=string:to_integer(Token), Int end|| Token<-string:tokens(String," ")].
[8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

[list_to_integer(X)|| X<-string:tokens(String," ")].